# How can I hide ajax search results when input text is cleared?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
I could finally get my ajax search work, but I couldn't hide the results when I clear the input text box. Also, I couldn't select the search result so that it should retain in the input text box
```

**Here is the Ajax code :**
**Ajax.js**

```
$(function () {
$('#search').keyup(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "search",
        data: {
            'search_text': $('#search').val(),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
        },
        success: searchSuccess,
        dataType: 'html'
    });
});
});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
$('#search-results').html(data);
}
```

**Here is the html template**
**Template.html**

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" class="search" value="Enter Loc" size="35" maxlength="300" style="margin-left:10px;color:#d5caca" onclick="document.getElementById('search').value = ''" />
    <a class="lr" style="text-decoration:none" href="#">Search</a>
    <ul id="search-results" style="color:#ffffff;margin-left:35%">
    </ul>
```

Thanks in advance to help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the result panel if the value is blank

```
$(function () {
    $('#search').keyup(function () {
        //clear result panel if the value is blank
        if (!this.value.trim()) {
            $('#search-results').html('');
            return;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "search",
            data: {
                'search_text': $('#search').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'
        });
    });
});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $('#search-results').html(data);
}
```

Comment: Hi Arun, Thanks a lot!, it helps.. How can I select any search result to make it retained in #search input text ?

Comment: How to select input search result ?, I'm using <li> tag for displaying search results.. How can I make result value retained in the input text tag when selected any value ?

Comment: @user3128771 sorry... I'm not clear on what are you looking for

Comment: Hi Arun, Currently my Ajax search results are displayed below the input text field in the form of list items... I can only see the results but cannot select any of those values.. what I'm looking for is that when I find the required result, I should be able to select it using mouse. so that the value will be placed in the input text field.